# Difference between increment and addition in this question?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int c[] = new int[n];
        for(int c_i=0; c_i < n; c_i++){
            c[c_i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(c);
        int t=0;
        for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            if(c[i]==c[i+1]){
                t++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

When I am removing i++ from if condition and making i=i+2 in for loop, the output is changing for certain test cases. Can someone explain me the reason as in both conditions i is incrementing by 2.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. In the second loop you increment “i” conditionally, not every iteration.

Comment: Incrementing i is always happening in the iteration, while the other increment is only happening when the two concurrent values are equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i++` inside your loop's body is only performed if `c[i]==c[i+1]`, so `i` is incremented by `1` in some iterations and by 2 in other iterations.

On the other hand, the loop's increment is always performed, so if the loop's increment is changed to `i+=2` (and the `i++` inside the loop's body is removed), `i` would be incremented by 2 in every iteration.

Therefore

```
    for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        if(c[i]==c[i+1]){
            t++;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

is not equivalent to

```
    for (int i=0;i<n-1;i+=2){
        if(c[i]==c[i+1]){
            t++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i is incremented by i` should be `i is incremented by 1`?

Comment: @SteveBenett that was a typo. Thanks